# Reasons for variations in sufficient statistic where order statistics $X_{(1)},X_{(2)},...,X_{(n)}$ are involved

Tags: statistical-inference, order-statistics

I need to understand an elementary part of sufficient statistics.

$X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n \space$ are a random sample.

> Let

\begin{align}
& (i) & & X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n \sim U(0, \theta), \ \theta>0 \\
& (ii) & & X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n \sim U\left(\theta-\frac{1}{2}, \theta+\frac{1}{2}\right), \ \theta>0
\end{align}

In both the cases the problem is to find the sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

Applying the factorization theorem, from $(i)$, we have

\begin{align}
f(\mathbf{x},\theta) & = \begin {cases} \frac{1}{\theta^n} & \text{if } 0<x_i<\theta, \space \space i=1,2,\ldots,n\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}\bigg\}\\
& = \underbrace{\frac{1}{\theta^n}\space \text{I}_{(\text{x}_{(n)})}^{(0,\theta)}}_{\text{g}\textbf(x_{(n)},\theta)}\space \underbrace{\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} \text{I}_{(\text{x}_{(i)})}^{(0,x_{(n)}}}_\text{h(x)}
\end{align}

From $(ii)$, we have

\begin{align}
f(\mathbf{x},\theta) & =\begin {cases} 1 & \text{if } \theta - \frac{1}{2}<x_{(1)}<x_{(2)}<\cdots<x_{(n)}<\theta+\frac{1}{2}, \space \space i=1,2,\ldots,n\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}\bigg\}\\
& =\underbrace{\text{I}_{(\text{x}_{(1)})}^{(\theta - \frac{1}{2} ,\theta+\frac{1}{2})}\space \text{I}_{(\text{x}_{(n)})}^{(\theta - \frac{1}{2} ,\theta+\frac{1}{2})}}_{\text{g} \textbf(x_{(1)},x_{(n)},\theta)} \space \underbrace{\prod_{i=2}^{n-1} \text{I}_{(\text{x}_{(i)})}^{(x_{(1)},x_{(n)})}}_\text{h(x)}
\end{align}

And from $(i)$ $x_{(n)}$ is the sufficient statistic for $\theta$ and from $(ii)$ $(x_{(1)},x_{(n)})$ is the sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

What I don't understand -

> In problem $(ii)$ $g(\mathbf{x},\theta) = \text{I}_{(\text{x}_{(1)})}^{(\theta - \frac{1}{2} ,\theta+\frac{1}{2})}\space \text{I}_{(\text{x}_{(n)})}^{(\theta - \frac{1}{2} ,\theta+\frac{1}{2})}. \prod_{i=2}^{n-1}\text{I}_{(\text{x}_{(i)})}^{(x_{(1)},x_{(n)})}$ then similarly in problem $(i)$ the $\mathcal g$**(x**,$\theta)$ should be equal to $\text{I}_{(\text{x}_{(1)})}^{(0,\theta)}\space \text{I}_{(\text{x}_{(n)})}^{(0,\theta)}. \prod_{i=2}^{n-1}\text{I}_{(\text{x}_{(i)})}^{(x_{(1)},x_{(n)})}$
>
> Why is not $x_{(1)}$ is an sufficient statistic in the problem $(i)$
>
> When $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n \space \sim U(\frac{-\theta}{2}, \frac{\theta}{2})$ the sufficient statistic is same as the problem $(ii)$, whereas the pdf is same as the problem $(i)$

I need to understand the reason that having same pdf why sufficient statistics change or having different pdf how come the sufficient statistic become similar when order statistics is involved. Any help, explanation is valuable and highly appreciated.

Comment: The notation of indicator function is confusing; it can be written in a much simpler way.

Comment: What do you mean by $U(\frac{\theta}{2}, \frac{\theta}{2})$? Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes there was a typo and I corrected it. By $U(\frac{-\theta}{2}, \frac{\theta}{2})$ I mean uniform distribution with parameters $\frac{-\theta}{2}$ and $\frac{\theta}{2}$

Comment: In the first case, $0<x_i<\theta\implies 0<x_{(1)}<x_{(n)}<\theta\implies 0<x_{(n)}<\theta$. But in second case, $\theta-\frac12<x_i<\theta+\frac12\implies \theta-\frac12<x_{(1)}<x_{(n)}<\theta+\frac12\implies x_{(n)}-\frac12<\theta<x_{(1)}+\frac12$. Do you see the difference?

Comment: @StubbornAtom, are we choosing the bounds of $\theta$ as sufficient statistics?

Comment: Sufficiency is about condensation of data without losing information about parameter; $x_{(n)}$ satisfies this purpose in the first problem. If you search the site, you will find these explanations in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $(i),$ the pair $(x_{(1)}, x_{(n)})$ is in fact sufficient, but it is not a **minimal** sufficient statistic, since a coarser statistic, $x_{(n)}$ is also sufficient. ("$A$ is coarser than $B$" would mean given $B$ you can compute $A$ but given $A$ you cannot compute $B$ without further information.)

Comment: +1 For you answer.